# How embedding_bag exactly works in PyTorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, torch, embedding, python-embedding

in PyTorch, torch.nn.functional.embedding_bag seems to be the main function responsible for doing the real job of embedding lookup. On PyTorch's documentation, it has been mentioned that embedding_bag does its job > without instantiating the intermediate embeddings. What does that exactly mean? Does this mean for example when the mode is "sum" it does in-place summation? or it just means that no additional Tensors will be produced when calling embedding_bag but still from the system's point of view all the intermediate row-vectors are already fetched into the processor to be used for calculating the final Tensor?

Answer (score 6):

In the simplest case, `torch.nn.functional.embedding_bag` is conceptually a two step process. The first step is to create an embedding and the second step is to reduce (sum/mean/max, according to the "mode" argument) the embedding output across dimension 0. So you can get the same result that embedding_bag gives by calling `torch.nn.functional.embedding`, followed by `torch.sum/mean/max`. In the following example, `embedding_bag_res` and `embedding_mean_res` are equal.

```
>>> weight = torch.randn(3, 4)
>>> weight
tensor([[ 0.3987,  1.6173,  0.4912,  1.5001],
        [ 0.2418,  1.5810, -1.3191,  0.0081],
        [ 0.0931,  0.4102,  0.3003,  0.2288]])
>>> indices = torch.tensor([2, 1])
>>> embedding_res = torch.nn.functional.embedding(indices, weight)
>>> embedding_res
tensor([[ 0.0931,  0.4102,  0.3003,  0.2288],
        [ 0.2418,  1.5810, -1.3191,  0.0081]])
>>> embedding_mean_res = embedding_res.mean(dim=0, keepdim=True)
>>> embedding_mean_res
tensor([[ 0.1674,  0.9956, -0.5094,  0.1185]])
>>> embedding_bag_res = torch.nn.functional.embedding_bag(indices, weight, torch.tensor([0]), mode='mean')
>>> embedding_bag_res
tensor([[ 0.1674,  0.9956, -0.5094,  0.1185]])
```

However, the conceptual two step process does not reflect how it's actually implemented. Since `embedding_bag` does not need to return the intermediate result, it doesn't actually generate a Tensor object for the embedding. It just goes straight to computing the reduction, pulling in the appropriate data from the `weight` argument according to the indices in the `input` argument. Avoiding the creation of the embedding Tensor allows for better performance.

So the answer to your question (if I understand it correctly)

> it just means that no additional Tensors will be produced when calling embedding_bag but still from the system's point of view all the intermediate row-vectors are already fetched into the processor to be used for calculating the final Tensor?

is yes.