# Equivalent of torch EmbeddingBag

Tags: pytorch, embedding

Torch claim that EmbeddingBag with mode="sum" is equivalent to Embedding followed by torch.sum(dim=1), but how can I implement it in detail? Let's say we have
"EE = nn.EmbeddingBag(n, m, mode="sum", sparse=True)", how can we replace the "nn.EmbeddingBag" by "nn.Embeeding" and "torch.sum" equivalently? Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How embedding\_bag exactly works in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052734/how-embedding-bag-exactly-works-in-pytorch)

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you for the reply. Actually, I had checked the answer before asking this question. I don't know how to implement it in a similar way for nn.EmbeddingBag instead of nn.functional.EmbeddingBag. It seems like that there is no number function "sum" for nn.Embedding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example where all four implementations yield the same result:

- [`nn.EmbeddingBag`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.EmbeddingBag.html):

  ```
  >>> embedding_sum = nn.EmbeddingBag(10, 3, mode='sum')
  >>> embedding_sum(input, torch.zeros(1).long())
  ```
- [`nn.functional.embedding_bag`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.embedding_bag.html#torch.nn.functional.embedding_bag):

  ```
  >>> F.embedding_bag(input, embedding_sum.weight, torch.zeros(1).long(), mode='sum')
  ```
- [`nn.Embedding`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Embedding.html?highlight=embedding#torch.nn.Embedding):

  ```
  >>> embedding = nn.Embedding(10, 3)
  >>> embedding.weight = embedding_sum.weight
  >>> embedding(input).sum(0)
  ```
- [`nn.functional.embedding`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.embedding.html#torch.nn.functional.embedding):

  ```
  >>> F.embedding(input, embedding_sum.weight).sum(0)
  ```